# IPv4 forwarding from RPi 2 to RPi Zero via OTG cable

Tags: networking, usb, pi-zero, iptables

I am trying to use my Raspberry Pi Zero together with my Raspberry Pi 2 and I want to share network access from my Raspberry Pi 2 to my Raspberry Pi Zero. I can easily create a local network connection between my Raspberry Pis, but I have a problem sharing network access.

First of I followed this guide, [Adafruit - Turning your Raspberry PI Zero into a USB Gadget - Ethernet Gadget](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget), to turn my Raspberry Pi Zero into a Ethernet gadget. Then I added this to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.0.1
```

I configured `usb0` on my Raspberry Pi 2 like this:

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.0.1
```

---

I could ssh into my Raspberry Pi Zero with `ssh pi@10.0.1.2` but my next goal was to share network access, so I could run stuff like `ping google.com` on my Raspberry Pi Zero. I found this guide, [Configuring Raspberry Pi as a Wireless-to-Wired Ethernet Island](http://www.glennklockwood.com/sysadmin-howtos/rpi-wifi-island.html), which explains how to forward network access from `wlan0` to `eth0` and I tried doing the same with `usb0`.

I added `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.conf` to `/etc/network/interfaces`. This is the content of my `iptables.conf` file:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Feb 16 16:41:38 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [472:58950]
:INPUT ACCEPT [324:32281]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30694:35635555]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [30694:35635555]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 16 16:41:38 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Feb 16 16:41:38 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [57:4180]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2194:2536976]
-A FORWARD -i usb0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 16 16:41:38 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Feb 16 16:41:38 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:821]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:242]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.115
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Feb 16 16:41:38 2016
```

I enabled ip forwarding in the kernel by uncommenting this line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Finally I executed `sysctl --system`.

---

Unfortunately the network is still unreachable on my Raspberry Pi Zero after rebooting both my Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi Zero. This is the output of `route` on my Raspberry Pi 2:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, I was really close to getting it right. Thanks to the awesome guys over at the [raspberry pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=136577&p=908453#p908453), I got it working.

What I did was changing the gateway on the pi zero to the ip of the pi 2:

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.1.1 #<-- I changed this
```

And removed the gateway from the usb0 interface on the pi 2:

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
        address 10.0.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        #gateway 10.0.0.1 <-- I removed this

pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.conf
```

After rebooting everything, I could ping any ip address within my local network. I had to add `dns-nameservers 10.0.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` to the usb0 interface on the pi zero to be able to `ping google.com` for instance.