# Raspberry Pi Zero OTG -> Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, networking, usb, pi-zero

I found [IPv4 forwarding from RPi 2 to RPi zero via OTG cable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/ipv4-forwarding-from-rpi-2-to-rpi-zero-via-otg-cable?newreg=85c026a2dcda4a8aa57992c1083c78c2) as a solution to my question, but there is a problem I cannot solve.

Raspberry Pi Zero works fine with Pi 3 but I can't connect any other device to USB when Pi Zero is connected. When I try to connect any kind of USB device everything goes into a loop of reconnecting (Pi Zero starts restarting itself, keyboard and the mouse suspend every 10 seconds; and if I plug USB drive it goes in a loop of appearing and disappearing `fdisk -l`).

If anyone thinks it's a power supply fault: I checked three different kinds (including my phone charger):

- 5 V 1.5 A
- 5 V 3 A
- 5 V 3.5 A

Comment: Checked the power supply how? By switching them out? By actually measuring the voltage at the board? Did you also swap out the cable?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Each charger had its own cable. I also changed Pi Zero cable. I checked the voltage on Pi 3 and it's okay. I connected several different devices (without Pi Zero) at the same time and all worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure with the OTG cable? Because an OTG cable would switch the Pi Zero W into USB host mode, and this isn't what you want, I assume. Instead, operate the Zero W in USB gadget (slave) mode by using a normal (non OTG) A-plug to micro B plug cable, connecting the Zero W to a standard A socket of your PC. The Zero W then acts as a standardized USB pseudo Ethernet adaptor and internally bridges this to its (gadget) usb0 network interface. An OTG cable has an type A socket, and it has one of its pins on the micro B plug specially wired. A standard A to micro B cable has only four wires.